# Bootstrap class="close" closes all modals

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal that is opened from another modal and when I close the last open, it closes both.

Here is The code of the last opened modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button id="closeMyModal" class="close"
            data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button> // This class makes all modals closes
        <h3>MyModal</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        [...]
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button> // This only closes the current
    </div>
</div>
```

I could change the class of the `modal-header` from `close` to `btn`, it solves the problem, but the css isn't the same.

How can I fix this ? Is it supposed to be the right behavior ?

Comment: Look at http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/ in the Stackable section and see the difference

Comment: if possible please make [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo...

Comment: @NikhilButani I've never succeed to include bootstrap in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your submodal div not inside the html of first modal. You should put that div in main window's ( the parent of first modal) body.